# java - forward inside Akka actor in ask callback

Tags: java, akka

We are using Akka with Java, when using forward inside an `ask` callback we do not get any response however when using `tell` instead it works just fine. So what is the difference?

```
final Message message = Message.builder().build();
final ActorRef sender = getSender();
final ActorContext context = getContext();

PatternsCS.ask(actor, Command.builder().build(),
        Timeout.durationToTimeout(Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS))).thenAccept(result -> {

    // do something with result
    ...

    // 1: Does not work
    actor.forward(message, context);
    // 2: Does work
    actor.tell(message, sender);

});
```

On the receiving actor when calling `getender()` in the first case evaluates to the `DeadLetterActorRef` in the second case it evaluates to the passed in `ActorRef`.

So why does `forward`not work here? What is the difference to `tell(message, sender)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `context` only while executing "inside of an actor", i.e. only during handling a message in `receive` or in one of the lifecycle callbacks.

When you use it inside of `thenAccept` then it will run detached from the actor in another thread even if the code is syntactically defined inside the actor class. In this other thread, the `context` will not be valid.

Your alternative to use `tell` with the original sender is the right way to do it.